# Mapbox GL JS: Adding a vertical offset to a label with a variable anchor

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to create a symbol layer with pin-like icons and a label displayed besides the icon [as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAsyx.png). The text should have a variable anchor `text-variable-anchor': ['right', 'left']` so that the label moves to the other side of the icon if it's colliding with other symbols.

Now the problem: because the icon is a pin shape, I need the icon anchor to be at the bottom (`'icon-anchor': 'bottom'`). The text label still positions itself to the original point causing the label to be lower than the icon, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9tlM.png). When using `text-variable-anchor': ['right', 'left']` the `'text-offset'` property stops working, therefore it seems impossible to move the label text up while retaining the variable anchor.

I also tried to use `text-translate`. This works, but then the collision boxes are not updated accordingly which causes labels to collide in to each other. Note that using a 'round' icon wouldn't have this problem. The icon anchor of a round icon would be in the center and therefore the text labels would position perfectly around the label.

Is there a way to use `text-variable-anchor` and adjust the vertical position of the label text when using an icon with `'icon-anchor': 'bottom'`?

Answer (score 0):

> When using text-variable-anchor': ['right', 'left'] the 'text-offset' property stops working

If this is true, it's a bug. That was meant to be fixed: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/8642

> I also tried to use text-translate. This works, but then the collision boxes are not updated accordingly which causes labels to collide in to each other.

That was supposedly also fixed: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/8598

> Note that using a 'round' icon wouldn't have this problem. The icon anchor of a round icon would be in the center and therefore the text labels would position perfectly around the label.

One workaround trick you could consider is making your icon centered by adding  blank space at the bottom, and using a center anchor. It will cause other issues with label collisions though.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the answer. They kind of fixed the text-offset property, but disabled for example the vertical offset when anchor is ['right', 'left']. And the vertical offset is exactly what I need.
About the workaround: you're right, only the label text will still be centered in the middle. Since the icon is blank at the bottom the text/icon combo is still strangely aligned then.